# AJAX Javascript Alert message Not showing on input Type="file"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, geojson

I am passing alert validation messages on multipart form which has also file field using AJAX, JSON in codeigniter. But alert message works on every form fields except input type="file". it show alert message on perfectly on every field but not on image field. For more detail i mentioned my code below if any error please help me.

### HTML Form Code ##

```
<div id="mes></div> 
<div class="form-group row">                                    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">                                                                                
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Title here">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">                                                                                
        <input type="text" name="detail" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Description here">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">                                                                                
        <input type="file" name="img" class="form-control input-sm">                            
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12">                                                                                
        <input type="text" name="orderby" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Order No">                 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 text-right">
        <label></label>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="search" title=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="save" title=""><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
        </div>                                      
    </div>
</div>
```

### Javascript code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{ 
    $('#formData').ajaxForm( 
    {
        beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm, options)
        { $("div#mes").html(''); },
        success:function(res)
        {             
            var result= $.parseJSON(res);
            $("div#mes").html('<div class="alert '+result.mes+' alert-dismissable" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'+result.msg+'</div>');
            if (result.mes == 'text-success') 
            {
                $('#formData').clearForm();
            }
        }           
    });   
});
```

### Controller code

```
public function save(){     
    $res = array();     
    //form field validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('detail', 'Detail', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('orderby', 'Set Order', 'required|is_unique[slider.orderby]');    
    //form Validation
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {           
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'alert-danger', 'msg' => 'Opps! Something wrong please check the fields below.'));          
        exit;
    }           
    // imaage configuration
    $config['upload_path'] = 'fassets/images/slider';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    //Load upload library and initialize configuration
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);            
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('img'))
    {       
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors('', '<br>');
        echo json_encode(array('mes' => 'alert-danger', 'msg' => $error));
        exit;           
    }
    //prepare data      
    $userData = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'detail' => $this->input->post('detail'),                               
        'img' =>  $this->upload->data('file_name'),
        'orderby'=> $this->input->post('orderby')
    );         
    //Pass user data to model
    $insertUserData = $this->slidermodel->insert($userData);

    //Storing insertion status message.
    if($insertUserData){
        $res = array(
            'mes' => 'alert-success',
            'msg' => "Record has been saved successfully.",
        );
        echo json_encode($res);
    } else {
        $res = array(
            'mes' => 'alert-danger',
            'msg' => "Oops! Something went wrong.",
        );
        echo json_encode($res);
    }         
}
```

Comment: If form validation passes and upload fails you should see your `$error = $this->upload->display_errors('', '<br>');`; you aren't?

Comment: Yes Error appear sent by backend but not showing in clientside...

Comment: I'm sorry: can you rephrase? Do you mean that you can see the json encoded error in dev tools but it is just not displaying?

Comment: Actually all (Form Validation and Display Error) are passes from backend but on client side only form error appear... if i left text field blank the error show... 'Opps! Something wrong please check the fields below.'
 But if I left the file field the error not show...

Comment: Ok, and when you fill in everything including the image does everything get correctly entered into the db and the image uploaded? I find it strange that the image upload errors aren't showing up as the code is the same as the form validation code.

Comment: yes if i fill all fields correctly then success message show up and record inserted in db. successfully

Comment: one more thing that very strange if i try to upload another format file expect image format like pdf and docx, Then errors show up on screen that it is not correct format... :)

Comment: Well you have is `<div id="mes></div>` missing a quote mark: `<div id="mes"></div>`. Don't think that's the problem. You should remove `$config['file_name'] = $_FILES['img']['name'];` because its redundant as CI already does this and maybe because it is undefined when no file is uploaded hence you are getting an "actual" error output rather than json. Also have you looked in dev tools > network > request page name > response to see the output of the ajax request under the "error" condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is your problem `$config['file_name'] = $_FILES['img']['name'];`

You can remove the above line as CI already does this for you!

When nothing is uploaded, and error reporting is on, you will get output that will state something like `Message:  Undefined index: img` in your ajax call. Thus your script won't be able to parse the json response.

For future reference you can debug ajax calls by viewing its returned contents in `Developer Tools > Network > {REQUEST_NAME} > Response` (invaluable tool).